# Here maps isn't working: "could not download initial data"

Tags: applications, maps

I've tried to install Here Maps on my phone (a Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus) and I've not been able to make it work.

The maps are not displayed at all, all I can see is a blank screen. If I try to zoom out, I will eventually see the whole globe, but just as a blue sphere, without any feature.

The strange thing is that if I try to search for a place I can get the pinpoint indicator, supposedly at the right coordinates, but, again, no map is displayed. It seems that some kind of data is accessible but the graphical part isn't working.

I have also tried to download the maps for offline usage, but when I try to do it all I get is the message "could not download initial data", and I'm even unable to see a list of the maps available for download. That same thing happen when I try to download voices, I get the same error and nothing is downloaded or even displayed.

Does someone else has experienced the sane issue? How can I solve this and make this app work correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this map app over Google maps?  Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the app?  Clearing the data in Applications manager?

Comment: Well, just because using Google Maps is not mandatory, there are alternatives and one can make his choices. :-) I've already tried both these things, without success

Comment: Absolutely you can make your own choice, just simply asked if there was a reason!  Sorry to offend you!  Good luck

Comment: No offence at all! :-)

Comment: If you have an ad blocker app installed, you might have to turn it off in order to download the map data.